# Need $6$ numbers that add to $1$ and form a line with slope of $0.2$: $y = 0.2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I generate "weights" for a weighted average that are straight line (not Exponential).
For example: $\frac1{21} + \frac2{21} + \frac3{21} + \frac4{21} + \frac5{21} + \frac6{21} = 1$

I have $6$ months of data and I want to "weight" the most recent months higher than $6$ month ago.

Wouldn't I be solving for this (assuming I want a slope of $0.2$)??

$y = 0.2x + b$

$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6 = 1$

I appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Is it necessary that $y_{k+1} - y_{k} = y_{j+1} - y{j} = \frac {y_6-y_1}5$? Or can they be *any* $6$ points on a line?

Comment: In other words, do you require that the numbers both add to $1$ *and* are in arithmetic progression?

Comment: .... well, I guess as for any $y$ we can find *some* $x = \frac {y-b}{0.2}$ so *all* $y$ are on the line if we have *no* restriction on the $x_i$.  So I guess the entire point of claiming they are on a line is to *presume* they are in arithmetic progression.  Correct?

Comment: I did not assume they had to be a progression ..I am exploring ways to perform weighted average on time series data that "weighs" more current periods heavier.

Answer (score 0):

Well $\sum y_i = 1$

$\sum (0.2 x_i +b) = 1$

$\sum (0.2 x_i) = 1- 6b$

$\sum x_i = 5(1-6b)$.  If we assume $x_i = i$ then

$\sum i = 21 = 5(1-6b)$ so

$1-6b = \frac {21}5$

$6b = 1-\frac {21}5=-\frac{16}5$

$b =-\frac {16}{30}=- \frac 8{15}$.

So $y_i = 0.2 i - \frac 8{15}$.

And that will give you the numbers you need.  But that assumes that your numbers must not only be on a line but also be in arithmetic progression.

If you know what $b$ is but you don't need that $x_i = i$ we can have any $\sum x_i = 5(1-6b)$ which for any possible $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ and $x_6=5(1-6b) - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3+x_4+x_5)$.

If you need $x_1 < x_2< ...<x_6$ then you let $avg(x_i) = \frac {5(1-6b)}6$ and $x_i$ be any $6$ numbers that average $\frac {5(1-6b)}6$ and label them in order.

Comment: I guess making them a progression will ensure they are equally spaced.  This is great - thanks - years of programming has made me math dumb.